# Call GetMethod from abstract class to get method of child class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have something similar to this

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public void BeginRequest()
    {
        var thisType = this.GetType();
        var methodInfo = thisType.GetMethod("DoSomething", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        Response.Write(methodInfo.Invoke(this, null));
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public static string DoSomething() {....}
}
```

Problem is that methodInfo is always setting to null. If I create DoSomething() inside Parent it works fine. I'm not really surprised that it doesn't wire up properly, but is there a way that I can make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add Public | Static modifiers:

```
var methodInfo = thisType.GetMethod("DoSomething", 
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy 
         | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public
         | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
```

Then it will search for public static method in current class or it's inheritors

Comment: Oops, thank you Jon. I've missed it from OP's Child example. Updated answer

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Will mark as answer as soon as Stack lets me.